# cropper library in android studio with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

Please introduce me a library that can display the image when the user enters the image from his gallery
Cut it any way you want

I want that library to have a hand cut.

and   I don't know if it is possible to find such a library or not, but if it has the ability to add text with desired size, color and font, it would be great, maybe this feature requires a separate library, I don't know.